# Is it possible to get values from my local machine to my form inputs tag?

Tags: javascript, python, html, linux, debian

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-panel">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Testing </h4>
                <hr />
                <form method="post" name="ibisaserver">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Address:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="interfaces" value="" required>
                        </div>      
                    </div>  
                     <div class="form-group ">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Network: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccionIp" value="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Netmask : </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mascaraSub" value="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Broadcast : </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccionGat" value="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

As you can see I have 4 inputs tag..

And I have this code as well:

```
with open("/etc/network/interfaces", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()
    print content
```

Where I'm getting the information I need from the following path : "/etc/network/interfaces".

Something like this:

[image]

Now, My question is: Is there a way to show the data I'm getting from my python or my local machine ("etc/network/interfaces") to my input tags?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways which you can use:

1. Make the python file generate the output html file, which you can use. [HTML.py](https://www.decalage.info/python/html) is a good option to start with it.
2. You can use XmlHttpRequest to read local files using javascript and populate the data automatically using JQuery.